# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.setState')

Tags: react-native

I encountered an error code while working on the project.

The error codes I face are as follows.

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.setState')
```

And this is my source code.

```
export default class MainScreen extends Component {
state = {currentSound:''};
  getData() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('soundState', (err, result) => {
      const soundSt = JSON.parse(result); 
      this.setState({currentSound:soundSt.soundNumber});
    });
  } 
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because `getData()`is not binded to the current scope oy the class. Fix it by using arrow function:

```
export default class MainScreen extends Component {
  state = {currentSound:''};
  getData = () => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('soundState', (err, result) => {
      const soundSt = JSON.parse(result); 
      this.setState({currentSound:soundSt.soundNumber});
    });
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks to you, I solved this problem well.